# Оптимизация SQL в Django(sqlite)

Tags: sql, django

[image: Таблица, к-во запросов и время выполнения.]

Добрый день. Собственно, я новичок в изучении Django. Думаю, вопрос простой.
Предположим, что у меня две есть две модели - Автор и Подписчик.
У Автора поля id, name, email
У Подписчика id, email, author_id(ForeignKey)

При отрисовке казалось бы небольшой таблички на 50 строк время выполнения уже целых 600+мс.
47 SQL запросов. Во вьюшке по сути только

```
return render(request, "subscribers.html", {"subscribers": Subscriber.objects.all()})
```

В темплейте:

```
{% for subscriber in subscribers %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ subscriber.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ subscriber.email_to }}</td>
        <td>{{ subscriber.author_id.id }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

И всё. Но каждая строка по сути отсылает свой собственный запрос в таблицу Авторов.
Из-за этого дичь получается по времени и куча sql-запросов.

Как это делать правильно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При выборке `subscribers` укажите `select_related('field_name')` или `prefetch_related('field_name')`. Тогда запросов должно быть 2

- [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#select-related)
- [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related)

Comment: Вау, спасибо! С .select_related('author_id') получилось 30 мс, один запрос. SELECT ••• FROM "main_subscriber" INNER JOIN "main_author" ON ("main_subscriber"."author_id_id" = "main_author"."id") ORDER BY "main_subscriber"."id" DESC